# RewriteRule works for one condition but fails for other

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

```
  Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
  # Turn mod_rewrite on
  RewriteEngine On 
  RewriteRule apartments  projects.html    [NC,L]  
  RewriteRule ^/apartments/cat/name2/?$    project-details.html    [NC,L]
```

The above rewrite rule was created to change url
**1) www.domain.com/apartments** to **www.domain.com/projects.html**
and
**1) www.domain.com/apartments/cat/name2/** to **project-details.html**

But **rule 1 succeeds** and **rule 2 fails**! Both **htmls exist**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^apartments/?$  projects.html    [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^apartments/cat/name2/?$    project-details.html    [NC,L]
```

Comment: now external scripts and css like this 
     `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">`  **dont work**. they are redirected to `apartments/cat/name2/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Comment: in your link href give full path from `http://yoursite.com/style/css/bootstrap.min.css` and then it work like charm.

Comment: always here to help :)